# Mongo: Import results of an aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

Sorry for the basic question, I'm new to mongo and learning my way around.

I have run an aggregate query in Mongo:

```
> var result = db.urls.aggregate({$group : {_id : "$pagePath"} });
> result
{ "_id" : "/section1/page1" }
{ "_id" : "/section1/page2" }
...
Type "it" for more
```

I would now like to save the results of this aggregate query into a new collection. This is what I've tried:

```
> db.agg1.insert(result);
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

But this seems to have inserted all the rows as just one row:

```
> db.agg1.count()
1
> db.agg1.findOne();
{ "_id" : "/section1/page1" }
{ "_id" : "/section1/page2" }
...
Type "it" for more
```

How can I insert these as separate rows?

I've tried inserting the `_id` directly, without success:

```
> db.agg1.insert(result._id);
2014-12-17T15:23:26.679+0000 no object passed to insert! at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:196
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$out`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) pipeline operator for that:

```js
db.urls.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : "$pagePath"} },
    {$out: "agg1"}
]);
```

Note that `$out` was added in MongoDB 2.6.